# ''Error input output while excuting Python"

Tags: python, input, centos, output

I have installed Pyton on centos 7 and when I tried to excuse the command Python I got the error:

> ./python3: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

So I have installed the package: `glibc-2.17-196.el7.i686.rpm`

But it didn't install the file `ld-linux.so.2` so I copied it directly to lib after that I am now getting the following error:

> ./python3: Input/output error

Comment: How did you install it? Those errors look like that system is very messed up.

Comment: Yes you are right the system was messed up I think it was the problem on the package I was using , I reinstall it again in my PC with command: yum install -y python3  and it worked perfectly.